# GPU not recognized in 2.92

Tags: gpu

so, I was previously on 2.91 and now installed 2.92. My Nvidia GTX 1660 Super is not available in the new version anymore. Anybody knows if this is a common bug and if I can do something about it? I searched around but didnt find useful and fitting answers so far.

I'm on manjaro linux.

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: I'm on 460.39 (Releasedate 2021.1.26). And I also installed cuda 11.2.1-2.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure then. With linux, you never know... it could be something to do with how Manjaro manages permissions to call on CUDA libraries or something like that. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to advise you further in that respect. The only linux I use is Kali, and certainly not for blender so i've never had reason to call on CUDA resources.

Comment: okay, weird. sometimes waiting seems to help. all of a sudden my graphics card appeard in the settings and I could select gpu as rendering device...

Comment: so it kept disappearing, but now I found out a trick in case anybody else needs it. I also have Blender 2.91.2 installed and after opening this (where my gpu was always recognized) the gpu would also show up in 2.92.0